# Using a php script to verify age of a visitor and loading an iframe based on result without refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

So yeah, that's quite a long title, let me explain.

What I am trying to do is a bit complicated, I have a webpage where I want to verify the visitors age and based on the result of that verification I want to load an iframe on the same page.

So I will use jquery to hide the iframe wrapper, set the iframe URL based on the results of the verification and then, with jquery again, I show the iframe with the right URL.

I am completely stuck, I have no clue on how to do this without a page refresh.

Allow me to show what I currently wrote, it's not functioning correctly but it might give you the right impression of what I am trying to do.

index.php:

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).onload(function(){
    $("#iframe").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myForm').on('submit',function(e) {

$.ajax({
url:'action.php',
data:$(this).serialize(),
type:'POST',
success:function(data){
console.log(data);
$("#iframe").show(); //=== Show Success Message==
}
});
e.preventDefault(); //=== To Avoid Page Refresh and Fire the Event "Click"===
});
});
</script>
</head>
<form>
    Please input your date of birth:
    <input type="date" name="dob"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Verify Age" />
</form>
<div id="iframe">
    <iframe src="<?php include 'action.php'; $iframe ?>"></iframe>
</div>
```

action.php:

```
<?php
$minAge = 18; // You might read this from a file/database.
$minAge *= 3600*24*365.25;  // $minAge in seconds

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $birth_date = strtotime($_POST['dob']);
    $now = strtotime("now");
    $age = $now - $birth_date; // age is in seconds
    if($age > $minAge)
        $iframe_url = 'http://URL1.COM';
    else
        $iframe_url = 'http://URL2.COM';
} ?>
```

What I was trying to do is set the iframe URL based on verification, then include that php to show the correct URL in the iframe.

Please someone that understands what I want, if you are able to help, I'll be forever thankful :)

Comment: try this <form id='myForm'>

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want page refresh, then action.php is not required.
Make the submit button type to just button.
On button click pass the values to a javascript function, and validate age in this function and display the iframe accordingly.

code for setting iframe url based on age: $("#myiframe").attr("src", "newwebpage.html");

Comment: how do I verify age using strtotime in jQuery ?

Comment: I have no idea how it can be done in jQuery. But you can do it in javascript:    var dateInMillis = Date.parse("04/06/2015");         Remember it converts date to MILLI SECONDS